# Access violation when trying to create 2nd vertex buffer object (VBO)

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, access-violation, particle-system

I am trying to convert a [particle system](https://github.com/Synxis/SPARK.git) written using fixed function pipeline to use shaders. It has few items like floor, rain, drops, splash.

I am using glfw, glad, and opengl ES 2.0, and since I am working on windows hence I am using PVRFrame emulator also.

I could easily migrate to shaders for floor rendering.

But while trying to migrate rain renderer which is in different class (which should not be an issue), it is giving below access violation exception which creating buffer using glGenBuffers(1, &VBO)
"Exception 0xc0000005 encountered at address 0x7ffa222e112e: Access violation reading location 0x000001c0"

I have gone through many resources which suggests to initiate glfw and context first but in my case, that has already been done and hence the floor rendering is working.

I want to render rain on the floor so the same window and context will be used. I don't foresee any issue with that unless I am wrong.

I have also unbounded the respective buffers from floor renderer before using them for rain renderer using glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0) and also have deleted the buffer using glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO). First unbounded it and then deleted it.

I am failing to understand why glGenBuffers should fail 2nd time and not the 1st time.

I do not think any code snippet is required for this scenario but if you want any specific info, I can tell that.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you declaring the VBO variable? The address in the error message says it's location 0x1c0 that's being read incorrectly... That's a very small address; these kinds of errors sometimes come from using a class member where the "this" pointer is null (0x0)... does your VBO variable happen to be a class member variable?

Comment: I am declaring VBO locally only and using it to generate buffer right away. When I abstracted out the whole buffer stuff into a separate class then its working fine. I am still unable to understand why local creation is failing. As per my understanding, the generation of buffer happens in the GPU so it should not be an issue whether its local or a class member. I know I am completely wrong somewhere in my understanding.

Comment: Do you get the error on the glGenBuffers call itself or does it appear later when you do a glDrawElements (or glDrawArrays)? If it appears after a draw call, it might be the case that you don't have a buffer bound at one of the inputs that the vertex puller is expecting to find or that the buffer that's bound is too small. Is there a way you can post the piece of code that's causing the problem (if it's not too extensive)?

Comment: I am getting the error on the glGenBuffers call itself. Right now, I have removed that code snippet and changed it to use class. I will try to reproduce it sometime later again and will post the code. Thank you!